# Why the particle does not appear in cycle render mode?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, eevee-render-engine

I follow the youtube to make towel texure by using particle. However, the texture can work in eevee render but not in cycle render. What is the problem or what steps I miss? Hope you guys can teach me, thanks in advance![image]

[Here is my file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T0uPc16R1FKwSno-bfftjgsSVfmzM7ZK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Adjust the Hair Shape, this works in only cycles, that's why the Eevee render different. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/hair/shape.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Your hair is not showing because the strands are tiny. You set them to 0.002cm and a scale of 0.01, so they are virtually invisible.
2. Don't mix a shader with nothing, unless you are going for a stencil effect.
3. Use a hair shader if you want to render hair. Normal shaders can work, but there's a reason hair shaders exist.

Hope that helps.